# How to zip lists in a list

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to zip the following list of lists:

```
>>> zip([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
```

This could be achieved with the current `zip` implementation only if the list is split into individual components:

```
>>> zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])
   (1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Can't figure out how to split the list and pass the individual elements to `zip`. A functional solution is preferred.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> zip(*[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

See [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

> The reverse situation occurs when the arguments are already in a list or tuple but need to be unpacked for a function call requiring separate positional arguments. For instance, the built-in range() function expects separate start and stop arguments. If they are not available separately, write the function call with the *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple:

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists for how this works.

Comment: I'd like to see an alternative in case you have a list with a million entries. It might not be a good idea to unpack a million items in a function call...