# How to zip the elements of a single nested list

Tags: python

Consider a nested list:

```
d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I want to `zip` its elements for this result:

```
 [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

How to do that?  An incorrect approach is

```
list(zip(d))
```

But that gives:

```
[([1, 2, 3],), ([4, 5, 6],)]
```

What is the correct way to do the `zip` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zip lists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112265/how-to-zip-lists-in-a-list)

Comment: this might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112265/how-to-zip-lists-in-a-list

Comment: What do you mean by "nuked"? Everything is alright, isnt it? :)

Comment: @tim  I clicked on that time-piece icon under the check-mark of one answer and Momentarily  _all_ answers disappeared!  Freaked me out.  I opened this page in a new tab and things were back. What's up with that?

Comment: Not so sure :) You should have rather clicked the "Accept Answer" on mine before this question got closed. But dont worry :)

Comment: i'm waiting another 10 seconds for min wait to accept your answer. That's why i had clicked on the time-piece: maybe it would tell me how much longer i needed to wait to accept Instead it nuked both answers from my page.

Comment: The same way as if you were calling *anything else* besides `zip`. You have a list of arguments; you want them to be used as separate arguments for the call; that is exactly what `*` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the single sub-lists via unpacking (`*`) as single arguments to zip() like this:

```
d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]          
zip(*d)  # You need this one
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

This even works for longer lists, in case this is the behaviour you want:

```
zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If you want to have a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, just do this:

```
map(list, zip(*d))
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: i originally tested with  `d = [a,b]` and tried `d=[*a,*b]`   . that did not work - but I might have happened upon this answer if had originally built it the way in the question ;)

Comment: `zip(*d)` returned `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]` in good old python2. With python3 you get `<zip object at 0x7f1af65288c8>`

Comment: @Friedrich   yea needing to drop `list(g)` on any  generator `g` is annoying.  I put a helper `def lmap(fn,x):  return list(map(fn,x))`  just to avoid seeing `list(map(...))` . too tiring to read

Comment: @javadba A bit evil, I use `xzip = zip; zip = lambda *x: list(xzip(*x))`. This gives old python2 behaviour for python2 and 3 .

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```py
list(zip(*d))
```

Comment: `list` need only for python3.

Answer (score 1):

you should unpack `d` before zipping it:

```
list(zip(*d))
```

The output is a list of tuples, as follows:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

I hope this fits you well.