# How to zip nested lists in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

How to zip a list of an arbitrary number of sublists so that you only recieve all sub-elements merged?

Have:

```
[[1,...],[2,...],[3,...],...]
```

Want:

```
[1, 2, 3,...]
```

Comment: You already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112265/how-to-zip-lists-in-a-list)

Comment: what should be the output for: `[[1,2,3], [4, 5], [6]]` ?

Comment: @JacksonPro no thats not excatly the same answer, just a part of it. The result should be `[1, 4, 6]`

Comment: ok, thx for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using nested list-comprehension and the asteriks argument

```
list_of_lists = [[1],[2],[3]]
[j for i in zip(*list_of_lists) for j in i]

>>> [1, 2, 3]
```